# CloudKit Dashboard - Setting the field that gets displayed in the left hand column

Tags: dashboard, cloudkit

I find the CloudKit dashboard buggy and lacking very basic features, which I find shocking for a product that is two years old and built by Apple.  Most of these problems I have found workarounds for.   However, I have been unable to find a workaround for my latest issue with the dashboard.  I hope someone can help me.

I have a record type that has numerous fields, including one called "patientName" (type String).  Until my latest change, when I click on "Default Zone" to view my records, the patient name would appear in the left hand column along with the record id.  This made it easy to scroll through the list of patients until I found the patient that I wanted to view or edit.

I just added a new field to this record called "patientAlias" (type String).  Now when I click on "Default Zone" to view my records, "No Name" appears in ALL entries in the left hand column.  This is the value of "patientAlias" field that I just added.  This makes it impossible to find a specific patient quickly.

Does anyone know how you can force the dashboard to use a specific field to display in the left hand column? Using the 'Sort by" pulldown has no affect on what gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently trying to tame the CloudKit myself :-)

CloudKit will use the field `name` or `title` if available. Otherwise it seems to just take a field of its own choosing.